# cant create array with STRING key

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create an **associative** array with objects, the key should always be a **string** (but they are always numbers).
This is how i store them (recording user clicks):

```
App.Recording[currentTime.toString()] = {sound: buttonName.toLowerCase() };
```

When trying to do this:

```
var save = {};

save.recording = App.Recording;
console.log(JSON.stringify(save));
```

I get this:

```
{"recording":[null, null,{"sound":"e"},null,null,null,.......,null,null,null,null,{"sound":"e"},....,null, null...]}
```

So, the `toString()` doesnt work on `currentTime.toString()`, which make my array store `currentTime` as numbers instead...

How can I save the objects and have an associative array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973706/javascript-collection/12973883#12973883) first. There are no associative arrays in JS. Instead of an array, you should use an object with a `for in` loop.