# Are null and undefined equally valid for explicitly making objects unreachable?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

According to [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19800805/1470607), it's best to make an object explicitly unavailable if you want them to be garbage-collected.
For all practical intents and purposes, does it matter whether that's done with a `null` value or an `undefined` value?

Shortly put, will both of the below objects (whatever they may have referenced originally) be equally accessible for the garbage collector?

```
window.foo = null;
window.bar = void 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter what value you assign: it might be `null`, `undefined`, `{}` or `42`.

What matters is that you need to break the connection between a variable and an object in heap.

As soon as an object is not reachable - it's a candidate for being collected, regardless on what the current value the variable that referred to it one day currently holds.

Here is a memory snapshots from a Google Chrome, just for fun:

[image]

And the corresponding JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9b5taxf/