# Javascript memory impact of null vs undefined

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, null, undefined

I work in an area where memory utilization is very important to us, as we don't run on your classic web browsers / hardware.

We use null quite a lot in our application, one thing that has not been clear to me is if null takes up more space than assigning a variable to undefined.

Do we know if one or the other is more costly on memory usage?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does null occupy memory in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499352/does-null-occupy-memory-in-javascript)

Comment: Check these answer: [What reason is there to use null instead of undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604749/what-reason-is-there-to-use-null-instead-of-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in [this jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/null-vs-undefined), null seems to be slightly faster in the chrome (V8, just like nodejs) which might indicate it being slightly more performant.

Since undefined is a longer string than null, the JIT compiler has to save 4 bytes more to memory when using undefined instead of null while parsing. Consider that memory aswell.

The garbage collection [doesn't care about the value being either null or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164680/are-null-and-undefined-equally-valid-for-explicitly-making-objects-unreachable).
The difference should be minimal. You should consider the consequences regarding [types](https://codeburst.io/javascript-null-vs-undefined-20f955215a2) of using null instead of undefined though. Enforcing the usage of either for the sake of performance might do more harm than good.

Comment: Thanks Tom - appreciate the response! From my previous project, I used undefined exclusively because of the typeOf issue with null returning as an object which I think is what you're referring to. 

On this new project though, where memory usage is critical I thought I'd ask the question as I haven't found much in my research.

Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome - but if you need full control over your memory, why don't you use another language like C#? You can manually allocate memory with that.