# Do JavaScript engines create a new lexical environment for closures ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8, ecmascript-5

When we have an inner function that access a variable `x1` defined in the lexical environment of its outer function, how the JavaScript engines handle keeping the `x1` in the memory ?

Do they keep the already created execution context with its lexical environment of the outer function or they create a new lexical environment and copy the variable binding into it then link it as the `outer` lexical environment for the lexical environment of the inner function and destroy the execution context with the lexical environment of the outer function.

Can we consider a `closure` as a `Lexical Environment` ?

- The outer function is `func1`.
- The inner function is `func2`.
- The outer variable is `x1` defined inside `func1`.

In the following code:

```
function func1() {

  var x1 = 1;

  return function func2() {

    var x2 = 2;

    return [x1, x2];

  }

}

func1()();
```

Comment: From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures): "A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared."

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*copy the variable binding into it*".

Comment: @Bergi, Do JavaScript's engines really keep all these environments instead of destroying them ! How is that possible because they are part of the their execution context which must be removed from the call stack after they executed ! right ! I have an assumption that what actually happens is that the engines create an object called a closure which a lexical environment to contain a references to the variables of the outer lexical scope and associate that to the [[scope]] of the function. Do you think this is a right assumption !

Comment: @faressoft Yes, the closure object does have a reference (the [[scope]]) to the lexical scope it was declared in. If a lexical environment is referenced by a closure, it must indeed be kept until it can be [garbage-collected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19798803/1048572) (and to be kept it's put on the heap, not on the stack).

Comment: @Bergi really great, so the lexical environment doesn't garbage collected after destroying the execution context because the there is a closure references to it.

Just one more thing, what references to what ? Do you mean the inner function stores a reference to the closure via the function's `[[scope]]` property, and the closure is an object that just has a reference to the lexical environment of the outer function ?

Comment: @faressoft The function object *is* the closure

Comment: @Bergi, thanks a lot, everything is cristal clear now :) You are genius.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155723/discussion-between-faressoft-and-bergi).